# titlesec and textpos: title name appears twice

Tags: macros, titlesec, textpos

I want to create a `block` type chapter opening where the chapter number and name are typeset in a coloured background.

I am doing something wrong with the `#1` parameter of `titleformat`, because the chapter name appears twice.

[image]

I want to typeset a very big chapter number and a chapter title (possible two lines) next to it; while the box for the background is defined by the paper margins and the size of the number.

I am trying to avoid using `tikz`, this is why I choose to use textpos; but using other package for the absolut positioning will be also fine.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{crop}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[raggedright, calcwidth, explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\newlength{\bleeding}
\setlength{\bleeding}{2.5mm}
\usepackage{calc}
\textblockcolour{red!80}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{%\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth+2\bleeding}(-\bleeding,-\bleeding)}%
}
{
}
{0cm}% sep
{
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth+2\bleeding}(-\bleeding,-\bleeding)%
    \vspace{\bleeding}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
    \hspace{2\bleeding}{%
      \resizebox{4cm}{6cm}{%
      \fontsize{148}{148}\selectfont
      \textcolor{white}{\sffamily\thechapter}
      }
    }%
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-5cm}
%    \vspace{-2cm}
    \fontsize{68}{68}\selectfont
    #1
  \end{minipage}
  \end{textblock*}
  \vspace*{-20pt}
  }



\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\label{sec:chapter-title}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiling your example I got the same result as you.

Additionally I got these warnings on the console:

```
Chapter 1.

Package textpos Warning: environment textblock* not in vertical mode. 
(textpos)                Environment textblock* should not have any text
(textpos)                or printable material appearing before it.
(textpos)                Alignment may work out wrongly. on input line 43.


Package textpos Warning: environment textblock* not in vertical mode. 
(textpos)                Environment textblock* should not have any text
(textpos)                or printable material appearing before it.
(textpos)                Alignment may work out wrongly. on input line 43.
```

So I inserted `\ifvmode\else\endgraf\fi` for ensuring vertical mode with the `textblock*`-environment.

Additionally I added `%` at lines which end with something that gets tokenized as character-token (e.g, `{` or `}`) in order to ensure that the space-character inserted at the end of the line due to LaTeX's `\endlinechar`-thingie won't get tokenized as space-token which in horizontal-mode might yield some horizontal glue.

After doing these things, the warnings disappear and the title of the chapter appears only once.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{crop}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[raggedright, calcwidth, explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\newlength{\bleeding}
\setlength{\bleeding}{2.5mm}
\usepackage{calc}
\textblockcolour{red!80}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{%\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth+2\bleeding}(-\bleeding,-\bleeding)}%
}%
{%
}%
{0cm}% sep
{%
  \ifvmode\else\endgraf\fi
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth+2\bleeding}(-\bleeding,-\bleeding)%
    \vspace{\bleeding}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}%
    \hspace{2\bleeding}{%
      \resizebox{4cm}{6cm}{%
      \fontsize{148}{148}\selectfont
      \textcolor{white}{\sffamily\thechapter}%
      }%
    }%
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth-5cm}% b instead of t -> baseline of last line of title will be aligned to baseline of chapter number.
%    \vspace{-2cm}
    \fontsize{68}{68}\selectfont
    #1%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{textblock*}%
  \vspace*{-20pt}%
  }%



\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\label{sec:chapter-title}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason for `\ifvmode\else` instead of `\ifhmode`? My innate laziness tends to the latter... `:-)`

Comment: @campa No particular reason but my own laziness regarding the question whether math-mode might be possible for whatsoever obscure reasons overlooked by me with all these packages loaded. Instead of spending time on that question I said to myself: The condition for the need of switching to vmode is TeX not being in vmode no matter what mode other than vmode it might be in. `;-)`

Comment: Just using the `%` was enough to have correct output. Thanks.